# pip install CrossMap failing on OSX: cannot find os/rand.c?

Tags: python, macos, pip, clang

Just trying to run a

```
pip install CrossMap
```

on OSX 10.11.6 with a brew installed python (version 2.7.12) and pip (version 9.0.1) and running into this error:

```
htslib/hts_os.c:30:10: fatal error: 'os/rand.c' file not found
#include "os/rand.c"
         ^
1 error generated.
error: command 'clang' failed with exit status 1
```

I have looked everywhere for information on this error and it has come up empty. Where does this dependency come from and how do I install it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`CrossMap` depends on `pysam` which is a wrapper for [sam tools](http://www.htslib.org/). You need to install [htslib](https://github.com/samtools/htslib) before compiling `pysam`.

Comment: Though `pysam` does seem to be the dep causing the problem.

Comment: I am not sure what is installed with `brew install htslib`. If only the library — it's not enough. `pysam` seems to be required htslib's sources.